# Multiple site same ASP MVC folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a site that I need to host for several clients. Can I have 1 folder containing all site files. And create sites for each client that use this one folder, but I need to change some things based on the client like connection string

Comment: Yes you need to use some server side processing. Store all connections in web confgi and select based on login credentials

Comment: what I want to do is create site in IIS for each of my clients, this sites will contain only custom content and fall back to(reference) a central folder which contains out of the box standard content(files, pages, classes)

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me. Prob better to have a lot of virtual directories running under one main site and assign each customer a custom url mapping to a specific virtual directory